# How to make max heap filled with std::pair in C++

Tags: c++, priority-queue, std-pair

We know `std::priority_queue` can be used to make a max heap. If I put a `std::pair` into it, it should be ordered according to the std::pair definition by comparing the first element and then the next:

```cpp
template<class _Ty1,
    class _Ty2> inline
    constexpr bool operator<(const pair<_Ty1, _Ty2>& _Left,
        const pair<_Ty1, _Ty2>& _Right)
    {   // test if _Left < _Right for pairs
    return (_Left.first < _Right.first ||
        (!(_Right.first < _Left.first) && _Left.second < _Right.second));
    }
```

However, the following code has strange behavior.

```cpp
vector<int> B{13,25,32,11};
priority_queue<pair<int, int>> Q;
for (int i = 0; i < B.size(); ++i)
    Q.emplace(B[i], i);
```

The numbers of Q are not ordered. WHY!? Q is shown in
[image: The content of Q in vs2015]

Comment: `The numbers of Q are not ordered. WHY!?` because a max-heap is not (fully) ordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are ordered. Your IDE is showing you the order of pairs in the vector that underlies your priority queue. See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) on how a heap is usually represented in array form to understand why they appear in this exact order. If you actually pop the elements of your queue one by one the will be returned in the correct order:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> B{13,25,32,11};
  std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>> Q;
  for (int i = 0; i < B.size(); ++i)
    Q.emplace(B[i], i);

  while (!Q.empty()) {
    auto P(Q.top());
    Q.pop();

    std::cout << P.first << ", " << P.second << '\n';
  }
}
```

Will print:

```
32, 2
25, 1
13, 0
11, 3
```

Comment: That is what I want. The underlying data structure of priority queue is a heap. And a heap is a binary tree expressed with a vector. E.g. the first element is bigger than the second and the third in a priority queue. The second and third have no size of relationship. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The [deduction changed in c++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/deduction_guides) - you can compile it in c++17 and your code will work. You have to parse your code according to cpp20 guidelines.